# Nginx Proxy serving PWA offline.html

Tags: nginx, vaadin, progressive-web-apps, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have configured *Nginx* as *Reverse Proxy* in front of *Vaadin v21* running on *Tomcat*. *Vaadin* is configured with `@PWA(..., offlinePath="offline.html")`. If *Tomcat* is offline a `502 Bad Gateway` is thrown and displayed by *Nginx* pointing to its own `/50x.html` resource. This error handling can be disabled inside `nginx.conf`. I then expect `offline.html` to be served from my browsers local storage (cache). However this is not the case. *Nginx* still serves a default 502 page.

**Is it possible to have *Nginx* reference my browsers local cache just as when I am not having a *reverse proxy* in front?**

If this is not possible I guess I have to create a `502.html` and configure it to be served by `Nginx` as it's own resource.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered asking nginx to serve as a caching proxy? Based loosely on  [this example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/), I made a few alterations and here is what I use:

```
http {
  proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:50m inactive=1d;
server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass             http://1.2.3.4;
    proxy_set_header       Host $host;
    proxy_buffering        on;
    proxy_cache            STATIC;
    proxy_cache_valid      1m;
    proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }
  }
}
```

You will certainly want to modify the proxy_pass URL, and likely the proxy_cache_path path. Some other values that warrant attention:

- I set the shared zone to contain up to 50 megabytes of data. You may adjust that number to your liking.
- I set inactive to 1 day. After 1 day, the cache will be retired.
- I set proxy_cache_valid to 1m -- after this, the cache will be considered stale.

The most important directive above is the proxy_cache_use_stale. This, I believe, solves the problem you identified: when the app is offline, and therefore nginx normally yields a 502 error, this tells nginx to instead serve from the stale cache.